# clang - symbol(variable, function, type, etc..) definition or declaration or reference

Tags: c++, code-analysis, clang

Please do anyone know if clang has option to return symbol definition or declaration(or reference)?

I mean: there is option for clang executable called -code-completion-at=path_to_file:line:coloumn
 the clang will look into code and returns you completion strings(ie if there is for example
std::string_type_variable. ..it returns to you all the methods and attributes you can call from std::string.

Now what i want is, for clang to return the file and coordinates, where the definition of the symbols starts .. so if it std::string_type_variable - i want to return to me coordinates, where i have writte std::string variable; in the code.

I want to use it in vim instead of cscope/ctags obsolete functionality(tags system using ctags/cscope in vim doesnt know context - its not usable at all in bigger projects)
I know there is clang followup(http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2011/10/vim-plugin-for-navigating-c-with.html) but it doesnt work correctly(actually doesnt work for me at all)

Is it even possible? it shouldn't be that hard, if it can return the completion, it probably already knows, where from he read the definition of the variable...

Comment: Why does it have to be `clang` that does this?

Comment: It doesnt have to be.. do you know about something else? Reasonably fast?

Comment: Vim now has [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) and [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) plugin that should meets your demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang provides such functionality by libclang shared library, but there is a simple example on how to use it. If you built clang from source, take a look at c-index-test executable. It's source located in tools/c-index-test.

Comment: thanx, i'll give it a look...though on first look it somehow doesnt work :)

Comment: So i've been playing with c-index-test and found out a lot functionality. Thanx much, its exactly what i needed. :)