# Can clang's c-index-test also find the declaration of a symbol?

Tags: autocomplete, clang, ctags

I have found [an older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889053/clang-symbolvariable-function-type-etc-definition-or-declaration-or-ref) question about a similar topic, but I am still wondering how to do this: I'd like to try to use clang for code navigation, instead of gtags / GNU global or similar tools. I am already using autocomplete-clang for Emacs, which works really well. But it does only completion. Now I would like to ask clang: "Where is the definition and / or declaration of the symbol in xyz.cc:42:23". Is this possible with either c-index-test or clang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang definitely knows where is the definition of the symbol. I switched from clang-autocomplete to [clang-autocomplete-async](https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async) which uses `clang-complete` tool built on top of clang instead of stock `clang`. Although this tool does not support navigation yet, I believe it would be possible to implement it quite easily.

Comment: Great info. I did not know about that project yet, but it sounds worth checking out.